# How can I put required on a hidden field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a situation where I need the hidden field to be required, I used the laravel validation and put required in front of desired field but it's not working. I get the data in the request but required validation is not applying on it. Here is my code.

'product_image' is the hidden field I want to put validation on,

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name'    => 'required',
            'product_image' => 'required',
            'time_interval_id' => 'required',
        ]);
```

### Edit

product_image is just a hidden input text that contains image name

Comment: the product image is a file?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly: you want an HTML hidden form element that's being sent over to your application to be validated as required? hidden fields, being outside of the user's control, will always be returned with the value you set. If you wan't to make sure that the form wasn't tampered with, there's better ways. What is exactly the reason you'd want to to this, how are you doing it and how does it fail?

Comment: You want a required hidden field?.....

Comment: product_image is just a hidden input field @JavierLarroulet

Comment: @ZeeshanFaiz please review the answer I posted. The input type "hidden" does not support the "required" attribute as per HTML specification

Comment: @JavierLarroulet it's not about the html's required, but the laravel required. Like when you make a input field required in laravel, if not given throws error, I want the same thing for product_image , which is a hidden field.

Comment: Why do you need to validate the field as required in the backend when you are the one that controls if the field is sent with a value? The "required" validation in the backend is supposed to ensure that the user inputs information where he is supposed to. I'm a little bit lost on the "why" part

Comment: @JavierLarroulet The question here is not "why" but if it can be done, if so "how"

Comment: Let me rephrase. Why do you say it isn't working? You say "I get the data in the request" which means that the hidden input's VALUE is being sent to the backend, which means that the required constraint is being met, thus the form data will be accepted. If you're reporting an error, more information is required to reproduce it in some way

Answer (score 2):

Please note that HTML only supports the `required` attribute for the following input types:

```
text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file
```

Reference [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)

If your idea of setting a hidden field (which only you control) as required is to prevent form tampering, I'd suggest other methods.

Comment: I agree that's why I was so confused about the `product_image`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form enctype is multipart/form-data
 `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`